# React Native: Build Missing iOS + Android folders

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I recently update my React Native + React dependencies. I then removed by iOS + android folders to create fresh ones, but the following command that used to work in the past is now giving an error

**Dependencies:**

- React (16.11.0)
- React Native (0.61.2)

**What worked in the past:**

```
react-native upgrade --legacy true
```

**Error:**

```
error: unknown option `--legacy'
```

**What I've tried**

- I've even tried using just one dash too with -legacy
- react-native upgrade (Doesn't work since I'm on the latest version of
  React Native)

Answer (score 1):

You can create new iOS/Android folder using **react-native-eject**,

Follow this steps,

1. Remove old iOS/Android folder from Projects
2. Install @react-native-community/cli (`npm i @react-native-community/cli`)
3. Install react-native-eject (`npm i react-native-eject`)
4. Run this command for generate new iOS/Android folders `npx react-native eject`